# Monitor REST API using zabbix

Tags: zabbix

I'm completely new to zabbix and have not much idea about keys & functions in zabbix.

I want to send an email notification whenever response body contains "up":false

Answer (score 1):

You should start from the [quickstart guide](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/quickstart): it covers the basics, from item creation to alert notifications.